# Word search using grep command in Linux

Tags: grep

Suppose I have a file named as test.txt having content .
I want to find the line containing the words starting with "r" character and ending with "i" character?

Comment: Why is sql tagged?

Comment: What is that mean by \b on either side of the pattern

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like:

```
grep '\b[Rr][A-Za-z]*[Ii]\b' test.txt
```

That's case insensitive so, if you want to ensure specific capitalisation, you would adjust the individual character classes in the expression.

Comment: can be simplified to `grep -iw 'r[a-z]*i' test.txt`... but yeah, the expanded version allows easy modification for capitalisation, etc :)